# problem with igraph degree( ) function

Tags: igraph

I have an N x 2 table of integers called games[ , ].  The table of nodes/edges is converted to a graph:

```
net <- graph.data.frame(as.data.frame(games), directed=FALSE)
deg.net <- degree(net, mode='total', loops=FALSE)
```

(I realize that not all options are necessary.)

The problem I am having is that the degree distribution seems to be for in-degree only.  For example, the games file has the lines:

```
103 86
24 103
103 2
92 103
87 103
103 101
103 44
```

and yet igraph indicates that the degree for node 103 is '3' when it should be '7'.

Any insight in what I am missing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One thing that you should keep in mind is that most igraph functions refer to the vertices by their IDs, which are simply integers from 0 to N-1 where N is the number of vertices in the graph. If you have an N x 2 table of integers (containing zero-based vertex indices) and you want igraph to use the integers as the vertex IDs, you can simply use the `graph` constructor after having flattened the matrix into a vector by rows. When you use `graph.data.frame`, the first two columns of the data frame are assumed to contain symbolic vertex *names* (i.e. there is no requirement that they must be integers); these will be assigned to the `name` vertex attribute, and igraph will simply make up the IDs from 0 to N-1.

So, let's assume that you have an N x 2 matrix, one row per each edge:

```
> edges <- matrix(c(103, 86, 24, 103, 103, 2, 92, 103, 87, 103, 103, 101, 103, 44), ncol=2, byrow=T)
```

First we create a graph out of it after flattening the matrix by rows:

```
> g <- graph(as.vector(t(edges)))
```

This gives you a directed graph with 7 edges and the out/in-degrees of vertex 103 will be as expected:

```
> ecount(g)
7
> degree(g, 103, mode="out")
4
> degree(g, 103, mode="in")
3
> degree(g, 103, mode="all")
7
```

If you use `graph.data.frame` with the above matrix, igraph will construct a graph where the numbers in the matrix are stored in the `name` vertex attribute:

```
> g <- graph.data.frame(as.data.frame(edges))
> V(g)$name
[1] "103" "24"  "92"  "87"  "86"  "2"   "101" "44"
```

This shows you that the vertex with the name `103` actually became vertex zero in the graph:

```
> degree(g, 0, mode="out")
4
> degree(g, 0, mode="in")
3
> degree(g, 0, mode="all")
7
```

As far as I know, `degree` is also able to work with the vertex names directly if there is a vertex attribute called `name` in the graph, so you can also do this:

```
> degree(g, "103", mode="in")
3
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect! It's not what I was hoping for since it means somethings is wrong at my end :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You created a undirected graph. There is no in and out degree in such a graph. From the igraph documentation  [link](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/degree.html) you can get the general idea. Your deg.net will return a vector with all the degrees(per node) on your graph, similar to this:

[1] 2 1 1 1 1 1 1

If you want to get the degree of a specific node(in our example it's 103) you have to specify the node(appearence_order-1). In your example you are looking for the (1st_node-1), it's node 0. So you must type:

degree(net,0, mode='total', loops=FALSE)

Which will return the degree of node 0, "7".